# Dynamic site percolation of independant random walkers on 2d square lattice

Tags: phase-transition, brownian-motion, percolation

Really appreciate your help, I am stuck in a part of my research which I am not expert in.

I have a 2-dimensional square lattice with periodic boundary conditions(torus). I am placing one walker at each node at the beginning. Then I let the walkers do a lazy random walk, which means that with probability 1/2 they jump to one of their 4 nearest neighbors with the same probability in each time-step. Walkers are independent so they can occupy the same site.

I am looking at this problem as a site percolation problem, so if two neighboring sites have at least one walker on them they belong to the same cluster.

At t=0, the particle density on each of my sites is 1, so I am at the endpoint of percolation probability function. But as the walkers do their first jump the percolation probability will change because the density of number of walkers per site is less than one in each timestep.

I am looking for the time behavior of percolation probability function in this problem.

Any idea or relevant paper would be very helpful.

Thank You 
Klara

Comment: This is probably better suited to Mathematics Stack Exchange. If this is university level research, surely you have some idea where to find relevant textbooks or research papers? Hasn't your supervisor given any suggestions? Haven't you found anything useful from an internet search? ... I see have have already posted on Math SE and gotten a response :  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2014649. You say there you are looking for *analytical understanding of the problem*. The difficulty here is that we don't know your starting point. Try : http://www.mit.edu/~levitov/8.334/notes/percol_notes.pdf ?